Chaining together GDAL functions
I am trying to read three single band images and combine them in one 3 band image using gdal/python.
I have found a working solution but it doesn't seem optimal :
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np


red_path = "F:/B4.TIF"
green_path = "F:/B2.TIF"
blue_path = "F:/B1.TIF"

red = gdal.Open(red_path)
gt = red.GetGeoTransform()
prj = red.GetProjection()

red_img = gdal.Open(red_path)
red_band = red_img.GetRasterBand(1)
red_array = red_band.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)

green_img = gdal.Open(green_path)
green_band = green_img.GetRasterBand(1)
green_array = green_band.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)

blue_img = gdal.Open(blue_path)
blue_band = blue_img.GetRasterBand(1)
blue_array = blue_band.ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
driver.Register()

final_img = driver.Create("combined_colors.tiff",
                            xsize=red_array.shape[1],
                            ysize=red_array.shape[0],
                            bands=3,
                            eType=gdal.GDT_Float32)
final_img.SetGeoTransform(gt)
final_img.SetProjection(prj)


first_band = final_img.GetRasterBand(1)
first_band.WriteArray(red_array)
first_band.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)
first_band.FlushCache()
first_band = None

second_band = final_img.GetRasterBand(2)
second_band.WriteArray(green_array)
second_band.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)
second_band.FlushCache()
second_band = None

third_band = final_img.GetRasterBand(3)
third_band.WriteArray(blue_array)
third_band.SetNoDataValue(np.nan)
third_band.FlushCache()
third_band = None

final_img = None

Now I want to do the same steps but in a cleaner syntax and so I tried doing multiple operations on one line but it doesn't work anymore.
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

red_path = "F:/B4.TIF"
green_path = "F:/B2.TIF"
blue_path = "F:/B1.TIF"

red = gdal.Open(red_path)
gt = red.GetGeoTransform()
prj = red.GetProjection()


red = gdal.Open(red_path).GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)
green = gdal.Open(green_path).GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)
blue = gdal.Open(blue_path).GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray().astype(np.float32)

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
driver.Register()

final_img = driver.Create("combined_colors.tiff",
                            xsize=red.shape[1],
                            ysize=red.shape[0],
                            bands=3,
                            eType=gdal.GDT_Float32)
final_img.SetGeoTransform(gt)
final_img.SetProjection(prj)

final_img.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(red)
final_img.GetRasterBand(2).WriteArray(green)
final_img.GetRasterBand(3).WriteArray(blue)
final_img.FlushCache()

final_img = None

Anybody knows why the second code doesn't work ?
Thank you in advance
